# How to get this div to align center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this markup

```css
.course-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.course-flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-flex-row-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="course-flex-container">
  <div class="course-flex-row">
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>delete</div>
  </div>
  <div class="course-flex-row-2">
    <div>Read Chapter 1 to 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="course-flex-row">
    <div>Blaw 3100</div>
    <div>Due Date: 6/29/2017</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to align the `<div>Read Chapter 1 to 3</div>` but it won't align to center when I use `text-align: center;` I tried on the that `div` and on its parent `div`.

I removed `text-align` from my code as it was not working that's why you don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `justify-content: center` to `.course-flex-row-2`

```css
.course-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.course-flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-flex-row-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="course-flex-container">
  <div class="course-flex-row">
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>delete</div>
  </div>
  <div class="course-flex-row-2">
    <div>Read Chapter 1 to 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="course-flex-row">
    <div>Blaw 3100</div>
    <div>Due Date: 6/29/2017</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

any of the DIVs that you would like to center the content of add

```
margin: auto;
```

to the CSS. You can also adjust the top and bottom margin by using

```
margin: 10px auto; //center with 10px top margin.
```

or

```
margin: 10px 10px auto; //center with 10px margin at top and bottom.
```

however....

```
text-align: center;
```

would center text only, not elements inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Change Like this :

> First change `className` to `class`.

**After Change Like This:**

```
.course-flex-row-2{
    display: flex;<-----------------Remove
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
}

.course-flex-row-2 div {<--------------Add
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.course-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: red;
}

.course-flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-flex-row-2{
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
}

.course-flex-row-2 div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="course-flex-container">
  <div class="course-flex-row">
    <div>edit</div>
    <div>delete</div>
  </div>
  <div class="course-flex-row-2">
    <div>Read Chapter 1 to 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="course-flex-row">
    <div>Blaw 3100</div>
    <div>Due Date: 6/29/2017</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, right I copied my example that is inside reactjs so className is the valid way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with position absolute along with transform for inner div & position relative for outer div.

Check the same example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f2vvy6st/

```
.course-flex-row-2 {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid red;

div {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

put align attribute to the parent div, it should also work, (not recommended but will get you work)

```
<div className="course-flex-container" align="center">
```

Comment: Always avoid the inline styling.Your code should work but keep the standard while you coding. you already assigned className for your div but why you used inline styling

Comment: @MKVimalan I know we should avoid inline styles even though the specificity of inline styles are more than class, id, element level styles, but I thought to show him another way since all the other answers have the bests way of implementation. but good that you comment, because this align attribute is now deprecated and this answer should be avoided.

Comment: cheers man,As you mentioned that also correct and works fine if you use in your code.But i say give some more attention towards the standard

Comment: ya correct mate